# What is an InstrumentedList in Python?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

During some set operations I encountered this error in Python:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'InstrumentedList'
```

What is an `InstrumentedList` in Python? I only found a few references related to SQLAlchemy. Is this a SQLAlchemy implementation of lists or something?

By the way, it happens while doing:

```
set(self.some_list)
```

where

```
print type(self.some_list) # <type 'list'>
```

Comment: That error isn't caused by the type of `self.some_list` - it can be any iterable - but by the type of its items.

Comment: You are trying to convert a list into a set object. Since it is a list of `InstrumentedList` objects that aren't hashable, you cannot convert them. See http://docs.python.org/glossary.html?highlight=hashable

Comment: @delnan: I wasn't aware of that. Thanks! You gave me an answer to a question I did not ask but whose answer exactly was what I needed. Good senses! ;)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, SQLAlchemy uses it to implement a list-like object which is aware of insertions and deletions of related objects to an object (via one-to-many and many-to-many relationships).

Answer (score 10):

Yes it's part of SQLAlchemy API.  Here is the class reference:

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/collection_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.collections.InstrumentedList