# sqlalchemy: troubles creating and getting one to many relationship, Why do I get InstrumentedList instead of List

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi

I'm really newbie using SqlAlchemy, right now I'm using fastAPI, basically I need create an Indicator model which can have several nested parameters

this is my code

```py
class Indicator(Base):
    __tablename__ = "indicator"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True, index=True)
    name = Column(String, unique=True, nullable=False)
    indicator_lib_name = Column(String, unique=True, nullable=False)
    properties = relationship("Property", backref="indicator", lazy=True,cascade="all, delete")
```

```py
class Property(Base):
    __tablename__ = "property"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True, index=True)
    name = Column(String, unique=True, nullable=False)
    value = Column(sqlalchemy_utils.ScalarListType, nullable=True)
    indicator_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("indicator.id", ondelete="CASCADE"))
    # indicator = relationship("Indicator", back_populates="properties")
```

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel

class Property(BaseModel):
    id: Optional[int]
    name: str
    value: List[Any]

class IndicatorCreate(BaseModel):
    name: str
    indicator_lib_name: Optional[str]
    properties: List[Property]
```

```py
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61144192/insert-a-nested-schema-into-a-database-with-fastapi
# https://dev.to/brandonwallace/one-to-many-relationships-complete-how-to-2nbi
def create_new_indicator(db: Session, indicator: IndicatorCreate):
    indicator_data = indicator.dict()
    properties = []
    if indicator.properties:
        properties = indicator_data.pop("properties", None)

    new_indicator = Indicator(**indicator_data)
    new_indicator.indicator_lib_name = indicator.indicator_lib_name or indicator.name

    db.add(new_indicator)
    db.commit()
    db.refresh(new_indicator)

    for prpty in properties:
        # prpty["indicator"] = new_indicator
        property_model = Property(**prpty, indicator=new_indicator)
        db.add(property_model)
        db.commit()
        db.refresh(property_model)

    db.refresh(new_indicator)
    return new_indicator
```

```py
@indicators_router.post("/", response_model=IndicatorBase)
def create_indicator(indicator: IndicatorCreate, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    indicator_new = create_new_indicator(db, indicator)
    print("indicator ", indicator_new)
    return indicator_new
```

```py
data = {
    "name": "adx",
    "indicator_name": "adx",
    "properties": [{"name": "range", "value": [2]}],
}

def test_create_indicator(client):
    global data
    response = client.post("/indicators/", json.dumps(data))
    data = response.json()
    print(data)
    assert response.status_code == 200
    assert data["name"] == "adx"
    assert data["id"] == 1
    assert len(data["properties"]) == 1
```

the error is

```
>               raise ValidationError(errors, field.type_)
E               pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 1 validation error for IndicatorBase
E               response -> properties -> 0
E                 value is not a valid dict (type=type_error.dict)
```

when I debug the code I can see the properties filled correctly, it's getting the data fine but the structure is InstrumentedList instead of List, why? how can I convert this into a List or a better question: which is the better approach to achieve this?

the way how I create the indicator and parameters is the better one? or is there a more concise way?

thank you so much guys, hope you can help me in my first steps with SQLAlchemy

Comment: In case you want to learn more about InstrumentedList: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6654613/what-is-an-instrumentedlist-in-python

Comment: You haven't included `IndicatorBase` in your definition; but property isn't defined as loadable from ORM (i.e. with `.foo` instead of `['foo']`. You can change this by adding `class Config: orm_mode = True` inside your schema class; this is why the pydantic class expects a dict: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/sql-databases/#use-pydantics-orm_mode

Comment: @MatsLindh that did the trick!, thanks, I had added `orm_mode = true` for  **IndicatorBase** but not for **Property** and that was the problem, could you include your answer in order to accept it as valid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Property` schema isn't defined as loadable from ORM (i.e. with .foo instead of ['foo'] in the source object).

You can change this by adding

```
class Config: 
    orm_mode = True
```

inside your schema class. Since this isn't present pydantic expects a dict-alike (i.e. that the properties can be resolved through a dictionary lookup).